# yield return in custom foreach not working as expected

Tags: c#, yield

I have an overrided `SaveChangesAsync` EF method as following:

```
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ChangeTracker
            .Entries()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
            .Select(e => e.Entity as BaseEntity)
            .ForEach(e => e.ModifiedOn = e.CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now);

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

`BaseEntity` is also my class with some common properties like `CreatedOn` and every entity inherits from this class. This overrided method uses my own `ForEach` extension:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            action(item);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

And the **foreach loop is not executing when there is a yield statement**. If I change it to this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            action(item);
        }

        return enumerable;
    }
```

Then it works perfectly. Why does yield is not executing it this iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Deferred execution.** The code is executed at the time when you *consume* the yielded items, eg. by looping over the result or by calling `.ToList()` on it. In your code example it seems like you never consume the result of the iteration, so it is never executed.

Answer (score 2):

Because an iterator needs to iterate

Call `ToList();`

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> You use a yield return statement to return each element one at
>   a time.
>
> You consume an iterator method by using a foreach statement or LINQ
>   query. **Each iteration** of the foreach loop **calls the iterator method**.
>   **When a yield return statement is reached in the iterator method,
>   expression is returned**, and the current location in code is retained.
>   Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the
>   iterator function is called.

**In short**

The call to `ForEach` **doesn't execute the body of the method**. Instead the call returns an IEnumerable, Since nothing enumerates over it, the method doesn't even hit the body at all as it has never started iterating.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `yield return` or `yield break` your code will only be executed if someone iterates over the `IEnumerable<T>` you get from the function.
The `yield`operator makes it possible to write lazy code.

Append `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to the statement, but I recommend `.ToList()`, because `.ToArray()` needs to create multiple arrays if the argument is not of the type `ICollection<T>`. 
[See](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d)